# Bixby command for currency converter

Tags: bixby, valueconverter

I wanted to try the currency converter feature of bixby where i ask it to convert the value from lets say USD to INR. This feature was in earlier updates of bixby. But when i tried it now, it wont work. If anyone could help me that would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you give us more information as to what you mean by "won't work", and the steps you took that led up to that event?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your questions is phrased, you should be presented a list of capsules that can address your use case.

For example, asking, "What is 50 Dollars in Indian Rupees" provides me with a list of two capsules that can serve this request. When I select one (I arbitrarily chose CNBC), I get the answer I requested, "50 U.S. dollars are equal to 3751.5 Indian rupees".